# jQuery UI, Making sortable accordian not auto expand

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

In this jQuery UI demo for the sortable accordion
http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#sortable
if you move something and it's collapsed, it expands automatically. Is there a setting you can add so that it doesn't expand when you move it? It should only expand when you click on it.

Thanks.

Comment: If I go to the demo and move an accordion, it doesn't expand in Chrome. What browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: ok thats weird, it works with IE9, but I was testing using Firefox 17 beta 4 or 5, and thats where it happens...

Comment: Perhaps a bug in the browser (particularly since its beta)?

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

You want to set the active element to false, but you also need to allow the accordion to be collapsible.

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: false, collapsible: true });
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uKTFk/27/

Comment: just tried this example, and it still opens the item when you move it when closed.

Comment: so i just downloaded ff 17 beta 5 and now it appears to be broken (in the way you described). it did work for the most recent stable version of ff though (when i tested it)